# Getting some errors when installing Magento via XAMPP

Tags: php, linux, magento, installation

I have a problem when you want to install Magento via XAMPP for Linux (I use 32-bit Ubuntu), some of the output error in the browser :

[screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCUHz.png)

I tried changing the file permissions :

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /opt/lampp/htdocs/shit
```

and

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /opt/lampp/htdocs/shit
```

After that I restart the `apache2` :

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

I tried to find a solution in Google, but it does not work, then what is the problem?
Is there a solution?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Where is the code problem in this question?   I think this belongs on ServerFault instead.

Comment: Hi there! What distribution are you running this on?